# Android - right side screen button

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, android-button, android-scrollview

I would like to ask you if it's possible to place a Button "above" another View. What I'm trying to achieve is an activity with ListView and a circle shape Button, which is "coming" from right side of screen. However, if somebody scroll down, button has to stay on it's position, and once he is pressed, new fragment is invoked. In fact, I got stucked at very beginning and have no idea how to do that, so every advice/hint/suggestion is welcome.

PS: Button should be used to add new item into ListView

Also, I've created a sketch for better explanation.

Thanks,
Regards

[image]

Comment: You could use FrameLayout.

Comment: Try placing thos elements inside a RelativeLayout and setting button's property android:align_ParentRight="true" and android:center_vertically="true"

Comment: Thanks for such a quick responses guys, however if I scroll down, button won't move down with 'Items' as well ?

Comment: Trying it out yourself is even quicker, but no, it won't move with the listview, 'cause it's not part of the listview, but of its parent view. You should read some basic android layout tutorial...

Comment: Thank @ElDuderino for your answer! Appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried for you and it works fine.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listAlertItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/clickBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_img" />
```

This is the result :

[image]

Comment: Thank you very mach @Farouk Touzi :)

Comment: Thanks to Juan Aguilar Guisado also :)